# Utilização do itálico em palavras estrangeiras

Tags: estrangeirismos

É uma regra utilizar fontes itálicas em palavras estrangeiras?

> Passe-me o ***ketchup***, por favor.
>   Hoje à noite, visitaremos um restaurante ***à la carte***.
>   Ele optou pela ***brätwurst*** grelhada.

Me parece que *ketchup* e *shampoo*, por exemplo, são palavras intrínsecas ao português. Ainda sim eu deveria utilizar a fonte itálica na grafia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve-se usar itálico no caso das palavras estrangeiras que não existem uma versão aportuguesada e não tenham sido encorporadas ao idioma.

Segundo o site [Só Português](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/curiosidades/Curiosidades_italico.php), ketchup não precisa utilizar itálico. Já no caso de xampú que existe uma palavra aportuguesada, precisa da utlização de itálico. Nesse site, há uma lista de palavras que não precisam mais do itálico.

> Depende. Sabe-se que, na produção de textos escritos em língua
>   portuguesa, recomenda-se que sejam grafadas em itálico as palavras
>   estrangeiras que ainda não tenham sido incorporadas ao idioma. Nesse
>   sentido, é importante que se conheça uma série de palavras que não
>   requerem o uso do itálico, uma vez que já foram incorporadas ao
>   português.
>
> De acordo com o Manual de Comunicação do Senado Federal, não se
>   utiliza itálico nos seguintes estrangeirismos:
>
> A: a posteriori, a priori, abstract, ad hoc, affaire, airbag,
>   antidoping B: baby, baby-doll, baby-sitter, backup, bacon, banner,
>   barman, bar-mitzvá, beagle, best-seller, bit, blitz, blog, blues,
>   blush, boom, breakfast, brie, briefing, brownie, browser, brunch,
>   buffet, bug, bureau, byte C: camping, campus, caput, carpaccio,
>   cashmere, chantilly, chat, checklist, check-in, check-out, check-up,
>   cheddar, chef, chester, chip, chop-suey, clipping, close, closet,
>   coffee-break, commodity, copyright, corpus, curry D: deadline,
>   default, design, designer, desktop, display, doping, download, drink,
>   dumping E: e-book, e-mail, expert, expertise F: factoring, fast-food,
>   feedback, feeling, flash, flashback, flat, fondue, freelancer, free
>   shop, freezer, funk G: gadget, game, gay, gentleman, gigabyte,
>   glamour, golf, gospel, gourmet, grill, gruyère H: habeas corpus,
>   habeas data, hacker, hall, hamster, happy hour, hardware, hit, hobby 
>   I: iceberg, influenza, in natura, in vitro, input, insight, ipsis
>   litteris  J: jazz, jeans, jingle, jogging, joystick K: kart, ketchup,
>   know-how  L: lady, laptop, laser, lato sensu, leasing, light, link,
>   lobby, log in, log off, log on M: make-up, marketing, marshmallow,
>   mignon, milk-shake, miss, mister, mouse, muffin N: nécessaire, net,
>   notebook, nylon O: off, office-boy, off-line, on-line, outdoor,
>   outlet, overbooking, oxford  P: paella, patchwork, pedigree, pen
>   drive, per capita, performance, pickles, pickup, piercing, pin-up,
>   pixel, pizza, playback, playboy, playground, pole-position, poodle,
>   pub, punk Q: quantum, quiche, quorum  R: rack, rafting, ranking, rap,
>   rapper, rave, recall, record, reggae, relax, release, remake, replay,
>   resort, réveillon, revival, rock, round, royalty, rush S: script,
>   self-service, set, shopping, show, showroom, shoyu, sic, site, slide,
>   slogan, smoking, smartphone, spam, spray, staff, standard, stand-by,
>   status, stretch, stricto sensu, sushi T: tablet, tailleur, Teflon,
>   telemarketing, ticket, timer, top, tour, trailer, transfer, trash,
>   tsunami U: underground, upgrade, upload  V: van, versus, videogame,
>   viking W: waffle, web, webmaster, wi-fi, whisky, workaholic, workshop
>   Y: yakisoba, yang, yin, yin-yang, yorkshire-terrier Z: zoom
>
> Adaptado de: http://www12.senado.gov.br/manualdecomunicacao